# ob_get_contents is empty following fputcsv calls

Tags: php

I have copied a function which you pass an array and a temporary download file. The array has lots of things in it (it comes from a simple select * from table query) and the file is in an empty folder with 777 permissions.

```
function array_to_csv($array, $download) {
    ob_start();
    $f = fopen($download, 'wb') or show_error("Can't open php://output");
    $n = 0;        
    foreach ($array as $line)
    {
        $n++;
        if (!fputcsv($f, $line))
        {
            show_error("Can't write line $n: $line");
        }
    }
    fclose($f) or show_error("Can't close php://output");
    $str = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    echo $str;
}
```

It runs without errors and calls fputcsv several hundred times for every row in my array.

However when it gets to the end and gets the output buffer str is empty. Is this a file problem or a buffer problem? When I look in the folder there is nothing there. Should there be?

Comment: You haven't output anything so why would anything be in the output buffer?

Comment: you are not `echo`ing anything out so you are not capturing anything in your buffer ... what are you expecting to be there?

Comment: but shouldn't fputcsv be writing content, it is called lots of times?

Comment: It's writing to a file.  The output buffer holds echoed/printed output.

Comment: `fputcsv` writes to the file you have opened

Answer (score 1):

> However when it gets to the end and gets the output buffer str is empty. Is this a file problem or a buffer problem?

The thing is that you are not outputing (`echo`, `print_r`, `var_dump`, etc) anything. It is empty all the time.

If you want to see the *whole-picture* modify to

```
    function array_to_csv($array, $download) {
        ob_start();
        $f = fopen($download, 'wb') or show_error("Can't open php://output");
        $n = 0;        
        foreach ($array as $line)
        {
            echo $line;

            $n++;
            if (!fputcsv($f, $line))
            {
                show_error("Can't write line $n: $line");
            }
        }
        fclose($f) or show_error("Can't close php://output");
        $str = ob_get_clean();

        echo $str;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your anwwer and I understand your point put the fputcsv function formats the array into a line in a CSV file with all the commas, quotes and so on. I actually got the code from here so I am surpised that such a major fact was overlooked: http://www.code2learn.com/2012/03/generating-csv-file-using-codeigniter.html

Comment: Figured it out: I needed this for the fopen:  $f = fopen('php://output', 'w')

Comment: @RobSedgwick quoting php:  (Windows) In contrast, you can also use 'b' to force binary mode, which will not translate your data. To use these flags, specify either 'b' or 't' as the last character of the mode parameter. The mode relies on you entirely :)

Comment: Please, mark this answer if it solved/helped in solving your problem.